# Positive Recurrence, Stochastic Proceses

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

I'm trying to show that if $x$ is a positive recurrent state of a Markov chain and $x$ communicates with another state $y$, then $y$ is also positive recurrent.

Clearly $x$ is recurrent and we know that because it communicates with $y$, $y$ must also be recurrent. But what we ultimately need to show is:

$E_yT_y < \infty$ knowing that $E_xT_x < \infty$.

My professor directed me to a theorem in the book that states that if $p$ is an irreducible recurrent set and $N_n(y)$ is the number of visits to $y$ up to time $n$, then

$lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{N_n(y)}{n} \to \frac{1}{E_yT_y}$

So I've recognized that if we consider the set of {$x$,$y$} we get irreducible and recurrent, but I'm still not sure how having positive recurrence of $x$ gives us information about the expectation of $y$.

Comment: So, is your problem the conceptual question of *why* "positive recurrence of $x$ gives us information about the expectation of $y$" or something else?

Comment: I'm trying to show that the positive recurrence of $x$ implies the positive recurrence of $y$ given that the $x$ communicates with $y$. The expectation stuff is just where i've gone with the problem thus far.